# Create a column that can act as primary key using first 3 letters of an existing column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table consisting of various make model variants of vehicles. I need to create an unique key using first 3 letters of the make column.

Sample dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(make = c('AUDI','AUDI','AUDI','FORD','FORD','FORD'), variant = c('A4','A6,','A8','EXPLORER','FIESTA','ENDEAVOUR'))
> df
  make   variant
1 AUDI        A4
2 AUDI       A6,
3 AUDI        A8
4 FORD  EXPLORER
5 FORD    FIESTA
6 FORD ENDEAVOUR
> df$ID <- paste(substr(df$make,1,3),rep(1:length(df$make)), sep = '')
> df
  make   variant   ID
1 AUDI        A4 AUD1
2 AUDI       A6, AUD2
3 AUDI        A8 AUD3
4 FORD  EXPLORER FOR4
5 FORD    FIESTA FOR5
6 FORD ENDEAVOUR FOR6
>
```

Expected Output:

```
> df
  make   variant   ID
1 AUDI        A4 AUD1
2 AUDI       A6, AUD2
3 AUDI        A8 AUD3
4 FORD  EXPLORER FOR1
5 FORD    FIESTA FOR2
6 FORD ENDEAVOUR FOR3
>
```

I am stuck as to how to change the numbering for every make in the ID column. Could someone please let me know how to go about it?

Comment: if want to be obscure: `df$ID <- gsub('.(?=\\d)', '', names(unlist(split(df$make, df$make))), perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could generate row number in each `make` and paste it with first 3 characters in `make`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(make) %>% mutate(ID = paste0(substr(make, 1, 3), row_number()))

#  make  variant   ID   
#  <fct> <fct>     <chr>
#1 AUDI  A4        AUD1 
#2 AUDI  A6,       AUD2 
#3 AUDI  A8        AUD3 
#4 FORD  EXPLORER  FOR1 
#5 FORD  FIESTA    FOR2 
#6 FORD  ENDEAVOUR FOR3
```

Or in base R :

```
with(df, paste0(substr(make, 1, 3), ave(seq_along(make), make, FUN = seq_along)))
#[1] "AUD1" "AUD2" "AUD3" "FOR1" "FOR2" "FOR3"
```